# Mixed datetime and categorical hierarchical index (multiindex) in pandas

Tags: pandas, ipython, multi-index

A dataframe `df` includes columns on `df['country']`, `df['sector']` and `df['year']` and there is other numerical data which is mixed `int` and `float`. Country and sector are `categorical` variables, year is `datetime64[ns]`.

I have created a 3-layer hierarchy as follows

```
arrays1 = [np.array(df['country']), np.array(df['sector']), np.array(df['year'])] 
df1 = df.set_index(arrays1)
df1.index.names = ['country','sector', 'year']
df1 = df1.sort_index()
```

How should you create this multiindex to ensure the third level `year` is recognized as a datetimeIndex of frequency annual?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['country','sector','year']).sort_index()
```

Then you can check `level` of `MultiIndex` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
print (df1.index.get_level_values('year'))
```

Comment: Thank you -- an eloquent solution. How about setting the freq, which currently returns none by your get_level_values() command, but I would like annual.

Comment: Yes, I create sample and you are right, it seems it lost frequency. Is some reason why need it? Because it looks like bug :(

Comment: I'll be doing time series analysis on the data from the statsmodels package. I think it will become important then.